My text is flowing out of the table
When I add text to the subsection where the table is situated, it makes the text inside the table flow out of the bottom of the table.

Code for the table:
\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Privacy Leakage example}
\centering
% Adjusted tcolorbox to handle text wrapping
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, width=\linewidth, 
    tabularx={>{\centering\arraybackslash}l>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}, 
    title={OPT SST-2 prompt}, 
    boxrule=0.5pt, colback=white, colframe=black!70, breakable]

Instruction: Classify the input text as positive or negative.
\\ >{}>{}> Generated instruct:
 \\{[START]} Student Output: positive  \\Correct Ouput: negative    Input: the film is a beautiful film , \\but the film is a little too much .   Student Output: positive  \\Correct Ouput: negative    Input:{[END]} \\
 {[\textbf{ALERT}]} Dump instruct. because privacy leaked for demo: \\ \colorbox{pink}{beautiful film} .
\end{tcolorbox}
\label{tab1}
\end{table}

the way tabularx maintains the code is exactly how I want the code to look like.
For example, this is how the table looks before the paragraph is added in the body before the table.

I use two column format for my paper.
Image 2 sits at the bottom left of the page.
And when the paragraph is added it moves to the top right column of the page and the error occurs.
PS. I have no idea what the [h! is mainly used for. I just looked up some table examples and this is how it was used.

you should almost never use [h!] the !  syntax was chosen to be a reminder that it is for use in exceptional circumstances to over-ride the document settings. [h] means do not allow this table at the top of the page, or the bottom of the page or on a page on its own (as t b p are not included)  so the option will typically cause the table to float more than necessary, but nothing should cause the text to over-print, that is due to code you have not shown. You should alway sinclude a small but complete document that shows the problem

Just a note: Why do you use a tabular(x) inside the tcolorbox if what you want to typeset is not a table at all? You could just place a few lines there without using any tabular context.

it's hard to see but where is your table here? you are defining a two column table with an l and X column, but the data has no & to put anything in the second column? {>{\centering\arraybackslash}l makes no sense as \centering has no effect in an l column.

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ... BTW: command ´\label´ should follow command \caption immedeatly.

Should >{\centering\arraybackslash}l maybe be >{\centering\arraybackslash}X?
